# Delete instance using SequelizeJS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I get an error using .destroy() in NodeJS with SequelizeJS. My instance is well deleted but I get this error :

Error : [object SequelizeInstance]

My code :

```js
// my delete action in dao
delete: function (id, callback) {
  this.context.ProjectCategory.find(id).success(function (category) {
    if(category){
      category.destroy().success(callback);
    }
    else{
      callback('Aucune catégorie avec l\'id :' + id);
    }
  })
  .error(callback);
}


// my controller
this.projectCategoryDao.delete(id, function (error) {
  if(error){
    console.log('erruer '+error);
    request.flash('danger', error);
  }else{
    request.flash('success', 'deleted.');
  }
  response.redirect(self.baseUrl+'/_index');
});
```

Comment: There must be something more than `Error : [object SequelizeInstance]`. What is the rest of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured it by now, it's because both `.error(cb)` and `.success(cb)` will return a first a parameter in the first argument of your function.

So `.success(callback);` calls `callback(withYourInstanceHere);`, so when you check `if (error)`

If you want to replicate the standard way of callbacks, you'd have to do this:

```
category.destroy().success(function(instance){
    callback(null, instance); // So this will pass null for your error.
});
```